# Зависит ли домен от порта?

Tags: node.js, dns, домен, ip-address, порт

Если посмотреть определения TypeScript типов к методу **lookupService** NodeJS-модуля **dns**, то порт является обязательным параметром:

```
export function lookupService(address: string, port: number, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null, hostname: string, service: string) => void): void;
```

Основываясь только на этой информации можно сделать вывод, что при одном и том же IP-адресе, но разных портах домен может быть разным. Но так ли это на самом деле?

Тут есть ещё один связанный вопрос: если комбинация **<IP-адрес>:<Порт>** валидна, то валидна ли комбинация **<Доменное имя>:<Порт>**? Хотя я видел примеры последнего, не уверен что это валидно. Кроме того, это противоречит сделанному выше выводу, согласно которому доменное имя *зависит* от комбинации порта и IP-адреса, а не присоединяется к доменному имени.

Comment: система DNS дает ответ только на один вопрос: Какой ip адрес у доменного имени X. Порты к доменному имени вообще не имеют никакого отношения. Когда происходит обращение по доменному имени, сначала идет запрос в DNS, получается ip, потом посылается запрос на этот ip на заранее известный порт. Никаких ограничений в скольких  доменах указан данный ip нет. Так что на один ip может ссылаться бесконечно большое количество доменов. И запрос будет отправлен на данный ip по любому из имен. Так что домен может быть разным даже на одном и том же порту, так как никакого отношения к нему не имеет

Comment: И это уже дело прикладной программы, которая слушает на данном порту как то реагировать или не реагировать на то, какой домен был указан. Вообще говоря программа слушающая порт только видит соединение пришедшее на ее ip и порт, она не знает и не может знать о том, как и с использованием какого домена к ней обратились. В протоколе http(s) вызывающая сторона явно добавляет доменное имя в заголовок host запроса (и поле SNI https) что бы принимающая сторона это знала. Так что это уже остается на совести прикладного протокола

Comment: Подозреваю что вам нужен не `lookupService`, а `resolve` https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnsresolvehostname-rrtype-callback

Comment: И смотреть стоит не только в определения typescript, но и в документацию https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnslookupserviceaddress-port-callback

Comment: Функция lookupService является обёрткой над [getnameinfo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getnameinfo.3.html), который не имеет отношения к DNS. Порт используется для чтения названия сервиса из системного файла `etc/services`, и DNS тут никак не задействуется

Comment: @Mike Благодарю Вас за комментарий! Много стало понятно. "она не знает и не может знать о том, как и с использованием какого домена к ней обратились" - наверное, она бы знать об этом по заголовку ORIGIN, если бы не возможность подделать этот заголовок?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Благодарю Вас за комментарий. Насколько я видел, resolve определяет IP-адрес по имени домена, а мне нужно как раз наоборот - определить имя домена (ну или несколько таких имён) по IP-адресу. Если Вам интересно зачем, то решая задачу валидации заголовка HOST в рамках разработки бэкенд-фреймворка, я думал сначала дать возможность пользователю фреймворка в конфиге помимо IP-адреса указать и домен (если такой имеется). Но потом подумал, что верить пользователю, что он укажет домен, соответствующий указанному IP-адресу, было бы неразумно.

Comment: @AlexeyTen А если мы можем узнать домен по IP-адресу, то зачем вообще заставлять пользователя прописывать вручную имя домена? Но после прочтения комментариев стало возникать сомнение, а возможно ли такое вообще. Если нет, то придётся предлагать пользователю заполнить поле "domains", а потом с помощью resolve проверить, соответствует ли каждый из доменов указанному IP-адресу.

Comment: «А если мы можем узнать домен по IP-адресу» — в общем случае это не работает. На одном IP может быть миллион доменов, но вы их ни откуда не узнаете.

Comment: @БоковГлеб Да, по ip узнать какие домены на него указывают невозможно. Я могу спокойно взять и указать в своей DNS на какое нибудь имя ваш ip и вы об этом никогда не узнаете, пока я к вам не постучусь именно по http и не передам это в заголовке. И да, я могу в этом заголовке написать все что угодно, даже если этого нет в DNS. Так что всегда более верно спрашивать именно доменное имя, а ip определять по мере необходимости

Comment: Дорогие друзья, благодарю всех за помощь в виде комментариев. Вывод на основе Ваших комментариев такой -  поскольку по IP-адресу в общем случае однозначно домен определить нельзя, то следует спросить домен(ы), а потом с помощью resolve проверить, соответствует ли каждый из доменов указанному IP-адресу.